# Find sub sequence with max sum in an array such that sum of any interval is greater than the sum of end elements in linear time

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization, time-complexity

Given an array of `n` strictly positive elements, it is expected to find a sub sequence `[a b c ...]`(where a, b and c are indexes) of the array such that sum of elements in the range `[a+1 b-1]` is greater than `array[a]+array[b]`. In case of the first index selected, `array[a]` must be greater than sum of all elements till `array[a-1]`. In case of the last index selected, `array[z]` must be greater than sum of all elements from `z+1`. If multiple sub sequences are possible, it is expected to give the sub sequence with maximum sum of elements. Also `array[i]` must be less than `array[i-1]` and `array[i+1]` for all `i`.

Apart from the naive solution with exponential complexity, is it possible to reduce the complexity of the solution, `O(n)` maybe?